# Sqlite3/C++ executes DELETE statement without changing the db size

Tags: c++, sqlite, sql-delete

How is it possible? I have a simple C++ app that is using SQLite3 to INSERT/DELETE records.
I use a single database and a single table inside. Then after I choose to store some data into the db, it does and the size of my.db increases naturally.

While there is a problem with DELETE - it does not. But if I do:

```
sqlite3 my.db
sqlite> select count(*) from mytable;
```

there is 0 returned which is okay, but if do `ls -l` on the folder containing my.db, the size
is the same.

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Explain why you think that this is a problem. The notion certainly doesn't come from your reading the documentation.

Comment: SQLite FAQ: [(12) I deleted a lot of data but the database file did not get any smaller. Is this a bug?](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q12)

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html explains that deletes, in fact, leave empty gaps.  You might be able to do the VACUUM to rebuild the DB and reclaim the space, but be cognizant of the notes in that page about ROWID's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you execute a DELETE query, Sqlite does not actually delete the records and rearrange the data. That would take too much time. Instead, it just marks deleted records and ignore them from then on.

If you actually want to reduce the data size, execute VACUUM command. There is also an option for auto vacuuming. See http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html.

Answer (score 4):

The scenario is listed in the [SQLite Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q12):

> **(12) I deleted a lot of data but the database file did not get any
>   smaller. Is this a bug?**
>
> No. When you delete information from an SQLite database, the unused disk space is added to an internal "free-list" and is reused
>   the next time you insert data. The disk space is not lost. But neither
>   is it returned to the operating system.
>
> If you delete a lot of data and want to shrink the database file, run the `VACUUM` command. `VACUUM` will reconstruct the database from
>   scratch. This will leave the database with an empty free-list and a
>   file that is minimal in size. Note, however, that the `VACUUM` can take
>   some time to run (around a half second per megabyte on the Linux box
>   where SQLite is developed) and it can use up to twice as much
>   temporary disk space as the original file while it is running.
>
> As of SQLite version 3.1, an alternative to using the `VACUUM` command is auto-vacuum mode, enabled using the [auto_vacuum pragma](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum).

*The documentation is your friend; **please** use it.*

---

Also from [the documentation](http://web.utk.edu/~jplyon/sqlite/SQLite_optimization_FAQ.html#compact):

> When information is deleted in the database, and a btree page becomes
>   empty, it isn't removed from the database file, but is instead marked
>   as 'free' for future use. When a new page is needed, SQLite will use
>   one of these free pages before increasing the database size. This
>   results in database fragmentation, where the file size increases
>   beyond the size required to store its data, and the data itself
>   becomes disordered in the file.
>
> Another side effect of a dynamic database is table fragmentation. The
>   pages containing the data of an individual table can become spread
>   over the database file, requiring longer for it to load. This can
>   appreciably slow database speed because of file system behavior.
>   Compacting fixes both of these problems.
>
> The easiest way to remove empty pages is to use the SQLite command
>   VACUUM. This can be done from within SQLite library calls or the
>   sqlite utility.

In-depth examples follow.

Comment: so, you're delete my answer and that's your revenge? oh, yes, you're copied contents from my link into your answer, and then delete my answer. that's dirty. shame on you.

Comment: @EvgenBodunov: I did not delete your answer, and I copied no content from your answer. Your answer was deleted by a moderator (casperOne) because it was flagged as "not an answer", because [links are not answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116301/how-should-helpful-answers-that-are-just-links-be-handled). Links can be used to _complement_ an answer, but answers should be a self-contained burst of useful information. If that information takes the form of a quotation, then that's fine (as long as the sources are cited, of course).

Comment: @EvgenBodunov: And shame on you for jumping to conclusions, accusing me of things without any facts, and being aggressive.

Comment: it was deleted right after your comment, so i thought it's you. Sorry if i was wrong. I don't think it's necessary to explain answer from FAQ. Because this question is similar to dozens of the same questions there.

Comment: Mostly I read questions about obj-c and iOS development and there is normal to post just link, explaining solution to question problem.

Comment: @Evgen: Then I guess moderation in those topics is of a lower quality; this is a site-wide policy. Note that your answer was _converted_ to a comment on the question, not deleted.